# Email Quick Action on case is not visible on community

Tags: community, email, case, customer-portal

I have Dragged Email quick action under **Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience actions** but no quick action is showing for Email under the case detail page of the community. Please help.

[image]

Following is the community case detail page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tried giving permissions to community users through the permission set but got the following error.

[image]

Seems like community users can not send emails from the community.

Having an [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdiwIUAR/allow-partner-portal-users-to-reply-to-case-email) related to this, hope to get a solution to this soon.

Comment: The link you have on "Idea" is your screenshot image. Did you intend to link to a Salesforce Idea Exchange page?

Comment: Link Updated @Moonpie